# Prove whether the statement is true or false.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Is the statement $\frac{d}{dx}\left ( \frac{sin^2x}{1 + cotx} + \frac{cos^2x}{1 + tanx} \right ) = -cos2x$ true or false? Prove whether it is or isn't.

I have tried using trig identities to no avail and have gotten as far as getting common denominators and made the rational function $\frac{sin^3xcosx+sin^4x+sinxcos^3x+cos^4x}{sinxcosx}$. I am unsure how to continue from here, or if I have even gone down the right path to find a solution. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need a little simplification, rather than going directly for differentiation.

$\frac{\sin^2 x}{1 + \cot x} = \frac{\sin^3 x}{\sin x + \cos x}$

$\frac{\cos^2 x}{1 + \tan x} = \frac{\cos^3 x}{\cos x + \sin x}$

Adding the above gives $\frac{\cos^3 x + \sin^3 x}{\sin x + \cos x}$, which gives using the formula $x^3 + y^3 = (x+y) (x^2 - xy + y^2)$, the result $1 - \cos x\sin x$, which simplifies to $1 - \frac{\sin 2 x}{2}$.

Can you now differentiate and get the answer from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the expression you wish to differentiate. Simplify $A$:
$$
A=\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}+\frac{\cos^3(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}=\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)
$$
where I have used $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. Now observe $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ and $-\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$. Can you finish the problem?